# Docker push an image to a repo that depends on other images

Tags: push, dockerfile

When I built my docker image, the docker file I had lines such as

`FROM realyunlong/cv_image
 FROM nvidia/cuda:8.0-cudnn6-devel-ubuntu16.04`

Output of `docker images`:

```
REPOSITORY             TAG                            IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
v1                     latest                         1786f4752d3c        44 minutes ago      3.73GB
<none>                 <none>                         dd1523103796        About an hour ago   9.83GB
nvidia/cuda            8.0-cudnn6-devel-ubuntu16.04   8d377158a37d        12 days ago         1.99GB
hello-world            latest                         e38bc07ac18e        2 months ago        1.85kB
realyunlong/cv_image   latest                         4f1b6063ff55        12 months ago       3.37GB
```

My understanding is that v1 is a docker image of my project that depends on other pre-built images like `realyunlong/cv_image` and `nvidia/cuda`.
(I don't know what `none:none` is)

How do I push my image to my private repo?
If I push v1 to my repository, will all the other image dependencies be taken care of?

Answer (score 0):

If you `docker push v1:latest` it will push that complete image and all of its dependent code; but it won't be recorded anywhere the names those base images happened to come with.

So if you moved to another machine and ran `docker pull v1:latest` and then ran `docker images`, you'd see the `v1` image but you wouldn't see its `FROM` image listed, and if you tried to directly `docker run` that base image or to `docker build` another image from the same base, it would get pulled from Docker Hub (or wherever).

Answer (score 0):

When you push an image to repository (private or public), it contains whatever you choose to include in its build. If your `Dockerfile` that you are building your image from starts from e.g. `nvidia/cuda`, it includes whatever `nvidia/cuda` includes and all your additions to it.

However, if you want to re-build the image in your new environment, you will need everything that you had in your old environment to do so.

Pushing to private repositories doesn't really differ from pushing to public repositories, except for the required authentication.